# Outlook Custom Form - Dropdown List Populated With Room List

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to pre-populate a dropdown list in an Outlook custom form with only the list of rooms available in the global contact list? I believe this is referred to as the global room list, but I'm not 100% sure. I want to make a dropdown list for location when scheduling a conference room through New Appointment that populates based on a potentially growing list of rooms, and I don't want the user to type in the name of the room manually, otherwise it won't reference the actual room to allow it to show its availabilty on the calendar when making new reservations.

If this is possible, can someone explain how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably related: [determine if addressentry is a room in addressentries](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9d911125-7e95-4d65-be3b-7bbc96d6b7a4/determine-if-addressentry-is-a-room-in-addressentries?forum=outlookdev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do the job. You might want to save the entry ids (AddressEntry.ID) so that you can reopen it using Namespace.GetAddressEntryFromID

```
set rooms = Application.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Rooms")
for each room in rooms.AddressEntries
  Debug.Print room.Name
next
```

Comment: Note that this fails for localized names, e.g. in German this would be "Alle Räume"

Comment: Yes, to open the All Rooms container, you need to look at the PR_CONTAINER_FLAGS property (0x36000003) using AddressList.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty and check if the 0x00000200 bit is set.